# Is $\log (2x)\log\left(\frac{\log (2x)}{\log (x)}\right) - \log (2) \geq 0$ for all $x > x_0$ for some $x_0$?

Tags: limits

In [this answer to a question on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13913/6689), I claimed that the statement referred to in my question is true; thinking about it more clearly, I find that I can't prove that that is the case, nor do I know any reason why it would be other than "looks like it when I plot it on wolfram". I tried to bound it from below by some non-negative function without making any progress.

Context: the reason I used this statement was to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) := \left(1 + \frac{\log 2}{\log x}\right)^{\log x}$ is monotonically nondecreasing in order to use the series expansion for polynomials, which I only know to be valid for $\log x \in \mathbb{N}$. Given that that's not the case for all naturals $x$, I tried to use the monotonicity of $f$ so I can use $\lceil\log x\rceil$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use, for $$ 0 \leq t \leq 1, \; \; \; \log(1+t) \geq \; t - \frac{t^2}{2}  $$ which works because, with $0 \leq t \leq 1,$ the power series for $\log(1+t)$ is strictly alternating, with the absolute values of the terms decreasing.

Taking $$ t = \frac{\log 2}{\log x}  $$ and $x > 2$ works out.

Oh, you need $\log (2x) = \log 2 + \log x.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works out nicely; now I know I didn't give a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside,
here is a simple proof that
$\ln(1+t)
\ge t-\dfrac{t^2}{2}
$
for $0 \le t \le 1$.

All that is needed is
$\dfrac{1}{1+t}
\ge 1-t$
for $0 \le t \le 1$,
and this follows from
$1 \ge (1+t)(1-t) = 1-t^2
$.

$\begin{align}
\ln(1+t)
&= \int_1^{1+t} \dfrac{dx}{x}\\
&= \int_0^{t} \dfrac{dx}{1+x}\\
&\ge \int_0^{t} (1-x)\ dx\\
&= (x-\dfrac{x^2}{2})\big|_0^t\\
&= t-\dfrac{t^2}{2}\\
\end{align}
$